# Sacar el valor de un input id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, variables, modal

Estoy pasando datos de una tabla a un modal para poder editarlo, todo ello lo paso asi:

**Asi lo mando al modal:**

```
<td class="otrotdfgaz" id="Producto<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>"><?php echo $res['producto']; ?> <?php echo $res['alias']; ?></td>
```

**Así los recibo en el modal**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click', '.pedido', function(){
                var id=$(this).val();
                var Idp=$('#Idp'+id).text();
                var Estado=$('#select2-1'+id).children('span').first().text();
                var Numero=$('#Numero'+id).text();
                var Fecha=$('#Fecha'+id).text();
                var Vencimiento=$('#Vencimiento'+id).text();
                var Producto=$('#Producto'+id).text();
                var Total=$('#Total'+id).text();
                var Tipo=$('#select2-4'+id).children('span').first().text();
                var Ref=$('#select2-3'+id).children('span').first().text();

                $('#pedido').modal('show');
                $('#eIdp').val(Idp);
                $('#eNumero').val(Numero);
                $('#eFecha').val(Fecha);
                $('#eVencimiento').val(Vencimiento);
                $('#eProducto').val(Producto);
                $('#eTotal').val(Total);


                //alert(Estado);
                if(Estado == 'Pagado')
                  $('select#select2-1').val('1').trigger('change');
                else
                  $('select#select2-1').val('0').trigger('change');

                if(Tipo == 'Alquiler')
                  $('select#select2-4').val('1').trigger('change');
                if(Tipo == 'Comprada')
                  $('select#select2-4').val('2').trigger('change');
                if(Tipo == 'Exp.Compartida')
                  $('select#select2-4').val('3').trigger('change');
                if(Tipo == 'Alq. Opción a compra')
                  $('select#select2-4').val('5').trigger('change');


                if(Ref == 'Sin asignar')
                  $('select#select2-3').val('0').trigger('change');
                else
                  $('select#select2-3').val('').trigger('change');

                 });
             });
    </script>
```

**Así los imprimo en el input del modal**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Producto</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont corpiii" id="eProducto" name="eProducto">
</div>
```

Lo que quiero saber si existe la posibilidad de igual que se imprime en el input a través de la id, existe la opción de imprimirlo en una variable, por ejemplo algo así???

```
$Producto = "no se como poner lo de eProducto";
```

Gracias!!!

Comment: claro que se puede, tienes que ponerle un <td name="algo" y luego recogerlo en jquery con el name.

Comment: Entonces en los td, les añado un name=“algo”, y luego como recojo la variable?? Gracias

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Imprimir desde PHP o desde javascript/html?

Comment: Imprimirlo asi mas menos. <?php echo $idalgo ?>, en ese echo tiene que salir lo que este puesto en el td name

Comment: Perdón pero sigo sin comprender qué es lo que querés realizar. Hay diferentes maneras de pasar de cliente a servidor o viceversa una variable o dato pero se me complica darte una respuesta.

Comment: Pued que no lo haya explicado bien. Yo traigo toda la información de los td al modal a traves de la id y el script que esta arriba. Eso es perfecto en los inputs traigo los datos de ese registro. Bien haya ahi lo tengo, pero ahora necesito que esa mismo info que traigo al modal llegue al modal pero en forma de variable php.

Comment: En ese caso, puedes usar [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) y enviarle en `data` un objeto con la info que necesites.

Comment: Pero en ningun momento se cambia de pagina, lo hace todo en un modal, así también se puede??

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82420/discussion-between-kleith-and-miguel).